# Как преодолеть UAC и установить службу утилитой sc.exe?

Tags: c#, windows, service

Как преодолеть UAC и установить службу утилитой sc.exe? Исходная программа запущена с правами администратора, но при выполнении

```
string full_path=install_directory+"myservice.exe";
string command = " create V24UpdateService binpath= \"" + full_path + "\" displayname= \"my_service_display_name\" start= auto";
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe";
               processInfo.Arguments = command;
               processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
               processInfo.Verb = "runas";
               System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Запуск происходит все равно с ограниченными правами и служба не устанавливается.

Comment: Какими свидетельствами, что проблема именно в том, что запуск происходит с ограниченными правами, Вы располагаете? Какое сообщение об ошибке выводит `sc.exe`?

Comment: Как вы вообще определили, что `sc.exe` не может получить нужных прав? У вас же консольное окно закрывается сразу после выполнения и даже сообщение об ошибке не видно. Нельзя же так делать! Получение сообщения об ошибке - это первое, что надо сделать. Запустите `cmd.exe /k sc ...`, чтобы увидеть вывод программы `sc`.

Comment: вывод sc.exe [SC] OpenSCManager: ошибка: 5:

Отказано в доступе.

Comment: В той консоли, которая осталась от запуска `cmd.exe /k sc ...` запустите `whoami /groups`. Какие атрибуты у группы `BUILTIN\Администраторы`? Как называется группа с типом `Метка`?

Comment: whoami /groups :

Comment: Группа                                          Тип                     SID          Атрибуты

=============================================== ======================= ============ ==================================
==========================
Все                                             Хорошо известная группа S-1-1-0      Обязательная группа, Включены по у
олчанию, Включенная группа
BUILTIN\Администраторы                          Псевдоним               S-1-5-32-544 Группа, используемая только для за
рета

Comment: черт, вот полный вывод http://pastebin.com/4jm4QpSq

Comment: Вы пробовали запустить Вашу программу на другом компьютере, воспроизводится ли результат? Когда я использую Ваш код, мне ошибку воспроизвести не удаётся. Если ошибка воспроизводится на разных компьютерах, то будет неплохо, если Вы составите минимальный законченный пример, позволяющий эту ошибку воспроизвести.

Comment: воспроизводится с выставленным на максимум UAC

Comment: У меня UAC находится в режиме "Запрос согласия", это максимум, который можно выставить через панель управления. Добиться того, чтобы Ваш код запустил программу с правами обычного пользователя у меня не получилось. Если исходное приложение запущено с правами администратора, то новое запускается с правами администратора без запроса. Если исходное приложение запущено с правами пользователя, то возникает запрос. Если запрос подтвердить, то новое приложение запускается с правами администратора. Если запрос отклонить, то `Process.Start` выбрасывает исключение, а приложение не запускается.

Answer (score 3):

Если исходный процесс запущен с правами администратора, то все дочерние процессы запускаются с такими же правами. Проблема у вас в чем-то другом.

Но для установки я бы рекомендовал использовать классы [`ServiceInstaller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`ServiceProcessInstaller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller(v=vs.110).aspx). Для установки надо воспользоваться методом `Install`. Замечу, что нельзя просто так взять и вызвать метод `Install` у обоих - они зависимы друг от друга и надо либо положить один из них в другой, либо положить их обоих в другой `Installer` рядом.

Из недостатков такого подхода - у `ServiceProcessInstaller` есть проблема с передачей параметров сервису (любые пробелы он считает частью имени программы и не забывает экранировать).

Поэтому, вероятно, стоит вообще найти [документацию](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/103000) по установке сервиса через реестр и сделать как там говорят.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Этот путь я рассматриваю, как альтернативный, но хотелось бы понять механизм, который препятствует моей идее решения. Это можно увидеть и при простом пользовательском сценарии: скажем вы имеете права администратора и запускаете cmd.exe. Так вот, пока вы не запустите его явно с указанием повышенных прав, все запущенное в этом шелле будет просто упираться в невозможность что либо сделать без каких либо запросов на эскалацию прав. У меня получается ровно та ситуация

Comment: Вот именно. Если запустить `cmd.exe` с правами администратора - то все дочерние процессы получат повышенные права автоматически. Здесь та же самая ситуация - если у вашей программы повышенные права, то `sc` также унаследует их.

Comment: но не наследует по каким то причинам.

Comment: Значит, у вашей программы нет прав администратора. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: PS о, только сейчас заметил - вы же используете `runas` и `ShellExecute`. Значит, права администратора `sc` должна получить в любом случае. Проблема точно в чем-то другом.

Answer (score 1):

Решил несколько иным способом, взяв код [отсюда](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sachin.nigam/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically11262005061332AM/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically.aspx).

На случай, если ссылка побьется: использовались [`CreateService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx) и другие функции из `advapi32.dll` через P/Invoke.

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются, так как могут стать неактивными. Более того, ссылки на англоязычные ресурсы без дополнительных пояснений также не приветствуются, так как не все участники сообщества владеют английским.
Пожалуйста, опишите подробнее, что именно помогает решить проблему, так вы сделаете свой ответ полезным для гораздо большего числа людей.

Comment: Раз решение найдено самостоятельно - отметьте, пожалуйста, свой ответ как решение как только это станет возможно. PS "самое главное" из ссылки в ответ добавил.